# Design Pattern semantics: Can the operation, given in example, be classifiable as a Factory Method?

Tags: design-patterns, semantics, factory-pattern

**Describing the question without code:**

If ***a Class' operation*** (that otherwise fulfills structure of Factory Method -pattern,) returns a copy of an existing object's reference, which is fetched by another object's operation, and used by it's known type, instead of instantiating a new object - can it be classified as a Factory Method?

In addition, if it is deemed as not-a-factory-method; Does it matter whether the process of creating a new instance of a ConcreteProduct happens within the ConcreteCreator, or not? *(Taking account that in JAVA you always end up returning a reference, so only pragmatic difference would be that we're creating a new instance instead of using an existing one - but does this make the whole difference whether we have a "Factory Method" or not?)*

**A minimal example in JAVA:**

```
interface Product { ... }
class ConcreteProductA { ... }
class ConcreteProductB { ... }

class ProductHolder
{
    private Product foo;

    /*
    * May return an instance of either ConcreteProductA or ConcreteProductB
    * Sets foo null, for attempting to mimic a composition relationship to holder, foo being moved into another composition relationship
    */
    public Product getProduct() {
        Product reference = foo;
        foo = null;
        return reference;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

interface Creator { public Product createProduct(); }

class ConcreteCreatorA implements Creator
{
    @Override
    public Product createProduct(ProductHolder holder) {
        return holder.getProduct();
    }
}
```

***Edit:*** Noting that I intentionally left unchecked whether method returns null or not, does this have any relevance to the question?

---

**(my) Arguments for:**

- (Most of all) It fulfills the GoF: Design Patterns -book's Factory Method -part's "Applicability" -section's paragraph #1:

> *"(Use Factory Method -pattern, when) ..CreatorClass does not know in advance, from which ProductClass the instantiated objects must be."*

[Possibly an incorrect set of words; I use a translated version.]

- It does allocate memory, for holding the reference to the chosen object.
- It is typecasted to it's type, known by Creator -class.
- It is defined within ConcreteCreator -class (referencing GoF: Design Patterns -book's UML diagram).

---

**(my) Arguments against:**

- It uses an existing object, therefore it doesn't create a new instance. *(Is this necessary, semantics-wise?)*
- It copies a specific object, not a specific class. *(Given instance may have existing altered states, as opposed to a newly constructed instance)*

---

**Related yet separate questions' posts:**

- [Is it still a factory if it shares instances across requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372703/is-it-still-a-factory-if-it-shares-instances-across-requests)

General answer to his/her question: *Singleton Factory*

Comment: For me, anything that returns an object to be used (not entity) can be considered Factory, even the object is new or old. Not same with builder though. The only problem for me is, how do you design the `Factory` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the code I assume there's going to be a `ConcreteCreatorB`, `C`, etc. at least some of which will really new up objects rather than reusing existing ones.

So, I guess it remains a Factory method as long as this is true. Otherwise, it's probably not one - and I can't see the point of making it look like one, giving names such as `createProduct()` and `Creator`.

Comment: Existance of ConcreteCreatorB, C, etc was implied - **yes**.  
However them "new upping" (instantiating) objects was **not**. 
The question presumes that all these subclasses will use the same re-use methodology. 
_(I'm sorry if the names seem misleading, but they are to keep this reference as easily comparable to other factory method -cases, as possible.)_

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. To me, `createProduct()` intrinsically conveys the idea that a brand new object is going to be returned. It's no longer worthy of being called a Factory Method if all implementations of it just masquerade existing `Product`s as new ones. Whether the object used to get the existing `Product` is an existing object, an object created for the circumstance or the `Creator` itself doesn't matter, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Exactly, _"all implementations of it just masquerade existing `Product`s as new ones"_. Though this answer contradicts with what Fendy wrote earlier in his comment to the question; so I'll see if any new points of view pop up. Thank you both though! :)